# Django order_by last week days

Tags: python, django, django-models

models.py

```
class short_url(models.Model):
    """
        This is a short_url class 
    """
    blocked = models.BooleanField(default=False)                                # To check whether URL is blocked or not 
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)                            # When URL is updated
    url = models.TextField(validators=[URLValidator()])                         # URL entered by the user
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)                        # When URL is created
    url_hash = models.CharField(max_length=10,unique=True,db_index=True)        # base64 encoded URL id  


class click_info(models.Model):
    """
        This is a click_info class 
    """
    user_ip = models.TextField()                                                # Store the user_ip
    user_agent = models.TextField()                                             # Store the user_agent
    http_refrer = models.TextField()                                            # Store the http_refrer
    hash = models.ForeignKey(short_url)                                         # base64 encoded URL id
    get_parameters = models.TextField()                                         # Store other get_parameters
    request_time = models.DateTimeField()                                       # When user made the request_time
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)                            # When click_info is updated
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)                        # When click is created
```

Above are my two models.I want to get total number of clicks for a particular url_hash for last week .For example if make query today then it should return data for the past week days only ...

`Mon:2,Tue:1,Wed:10,Thu:122,Fri:97,Sat:12,Sun:11`

Comment: Past 7 days excluding today?

Comment: You want the _clicks from last week_ or the _url that was created within the last week_?

Comment: I want click counts for last week  for a given url_has but the counts should be as i shown above....excluding today...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the last week week range and you can use date range query. For example.

```
import datetime
from django.db.models import Count

from_date = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)

click_info.objects.filter(hash='<value>', created_at__range=[from_date, datetime.datetime.now()])
    .extra({'date_created' : "date(created_at)"})
    .values('date_created')
    .annotate(created_count=Count('id'))
```

It will give a list of dict elements. You can manipulate further based on your purpose.

```
[{'date_created': u'2013-09-03', 'created_count': 1}, 
 {'date_created': u'2013-09-04', 'created_count': 1}, 
 {'date_created': u'2013-09-05', 'created_count': 1}, 
 {'date_created': u'2013-09-06', 'created_count': 3}, 
 {'date_created': u'2013-09-07', 'created_count': 1}, 
 {'date_created': u'2013-09-08', 'created_count': 1}, 
 {'date_created': u'2013-09-09', 'created_count': 2}]
```

You can use the below snippet to strip the day and count.

```
day_clicks = []
for item in items:
    day = datetime.datetime.strptime(item.get('date_created'), "%Y-%m-%d").date().strftime("%a")
    click_count = item.get('created_count')
    day_clicks.append(day + ':' + str(click_count))
print ", ".join(day_clicks)
```

**Result:**

```
Tue:1, Wed:1, Thu:1, Fri:3, Sat:1, Sun:1, Mon:2
```

Comment: Getting error `day = datetime.strptime(item.get('date_created'), "%Y-%m-%d").date().strftime("%a")
TypeError: must be string, not datetime.date`

Comment: What if the count of someday in this week is 0? I got "Mon:2, Sun:1, Fri:3, Thu:3, Wed:3" with your awesome code, but I wanna "Mon:2, Sun:1, Sat:0, Fri:3, Thu:3, Wed:3, Tue: 0", any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
last_week = now - datetime.timedelta(days=7)

short_url.objects \
         .filter(click_info__created_at__range=[last_week,now]) \
         .annotate(click_count=Count('click_info'))
```

Comment: This will give me the week aggregate not per day result ..I want per day count of the last week